# Samsung TV Duplicates Permission Websocket

Tags: websocket, samsung-smart-tv, remote-control

I am developing a samsung remote app and using websockets to connect to the samsung tv. I am opening socket through this url "wss://ip:8002/api/v2/channels/samsung.remote.control?name=". All of this works fine but there is an issue that the TV asks for the permission everytime I try to open connection through websocket. I have seen other competitor apps and in these apps the TV only asks for permission for the first time.

Can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured this out. All you have to do is add a token in the socket URL. When you connect to the TV for the first time or without having any token in the URL, the TV responds with a dictionary having that "Token" as a key/Value pair.
Just use that token while connecting to the TV.

SAMPLE URL:-
wss://ip:8002/api/v2/channels/samsung.remote.control?name=someName&token=tokenValue

Comment: hi , i am doing same thing to connect with my samsung tv through websocket but i am getting this issue in result. also can u tell what will be the token here ?

Comment: NSLocalizedDescription=The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “IP ADRESS OF MY TV” which could put your confidential information at risk